# Fetch returned value from call function in javascript using Odoo8

Tags: javascript, odoo

I need to know how may I be able to get the returned 'result value' outside the call function. I can access the value within this function but I am not been able to assign or get this value outside the function. I tried to create a variable outside this function, assign its value as `'my_var = result'`. But when I print this value outside function , its still 'undefined'. How can I assign the value correctly to a variable.

```
  function check_scheme(pro_detail)
            {              
                var prom_sch = new openerp.Model('promotional.schema');                                       
                prom_sch.call('show',[pro_detail]).then(function(result)
                {                
                  return result
                });                           
                   return prom_sch.call('show',[pro_detail])
            }
```

Any suggestion or guidance will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your `result` is `undefined` outside your function because this function is asynchronous when you call the value outside it the value of the result was not calculated yet so you need to wait your function to finish the calculation of the result then try to get the value.

To solve this problem there are two methods you can follow to get the values outside the function and call it anywhere

**1st Method** is to use `callback` it will help you to synchronize the function and get your data  outside the function.

**2nd Method** is to use JQuery `Deferred`  like this `var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();`it will help you to synchronize the function and  manage calculating the value to return it outside the function

Comment: I dont seem callback working in my case or Im doing something wrong